# Drawing dynamic primitives in Java SWT

Tags: java, swt

I have a C++/Qt background and am now learning Java and SWT GUI programming. I need to draw some primitive shapes (circles, rectangles, etc.) on an image. The shapes need to move on the image (ie. change its position in relation to the background, imagine a real-time updating map). In Qt this could be easily done by using `QGraphicsScene` and `QGraphicsItem`s but how to achieve this in SWT? I have tried to use `Composite` with `Label` which is close to what I need but I haven't found a way to add primitive shapes to the Composite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Canvas` control is specifically for drawing on. Basic drawing operations are in the `GC` class.

```
Canvas drawWidget = new Canvas(composite, SWT.NONE);
drawWidget.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

drawWidget.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {
    @Override
    public void paintControl(final PaintEvent e) {
        Rectangle r = drawWidget.getClientArea();
        e.gc.drawOval(0, 0, r.width - 1, r.height - 1);
    }
});
```

Call the Canvas `redraw` method to request that the control be redrawn. This will call the paint listener again.

Other Eclipse packages such as Eclipse GEF provide much more sophisticated drawing APIs.

Comment: And how do I update the position of the oval drawn in your example later?

Comment: You call `redraw()` on the canvas to force it to be redrawn. The paint listener will then be called again.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to do the trick. My way of finding the approach to this problem was a bit different.